# Overlapped point data

Tags: point, route, average, mesh

I have recently used QGIS and tried some mapping functions based on my data but I have faced an issue with creating meshes. My data is route-based with overlapping points and I want to visualize them by mesh (100x100m) and calculate the average in each mesh.

Could anyone help me with how to proceed?

[image].

My target is to display on average the data of the overlapping point.

Comment: [Create a grid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid), [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinbylocationsummary)